# Should I care about the number of classes in my game?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory-management, game-engine, game-development

Well 1st, I am a person who learns by himself from the resources available on the web, and I didn't have a college education in programming, so I hope everyone will excuse me if this question sounds silly.

I am learning how to create dialogue; I made the component reference a `ScriptableObject` which is the dialogue database; it holds a list of dialogue class which is only a class containing a string and a nested type. It contains the name and image of the speaker perfectly, but I just want to know if the number of elements effect the game's performance. Every conversation may contain about 20 classes or more, so if the game has 200 conversations this means the `ScriptableObject` will hold 4000 class instances. Is this right way to do this or should I do something about it?

**Do all of the 4000 class instances load into memory or does only the class that the component needs load into memory?**

So I really need help or guide where I start to read or topic for search to improve my knowledge about this. Thanks for helping me learn

Comment: Depends what exactly is stored in these classes but basically yes, all instances of classes that exist have to be stored somewhere in the memory

Comment: "all instances of classes that exist have to be stored somewhere in the memory" how i know when the ScriptableObject exist in the memory

Comment: Surely this question is about [tag:c#], not the javascript-like **deprecated** language [tag:unityscript]

Comment: This question is primarily opinion based, especially lacking any sort of [mcve], problem statement, or explanation of what _specific_ help is needed. That said: large numbers of classes aren't so much a problem from a RAM point of view -- unused code isn't brought into RAM, and if you need the code, you need the code, no matter how many classes contain it -- but rather from a conceptual/maintenance point of view. Your question lacks details, but it seems likely you should architect the conversation code differently, so that it has a single classes (or possibly a handful of classes) that ...

Comment: ... understands the basic mechanism of a conversation, but which then uses _data_ read from a resource or file that determines how the conversation actually works. Don't hard-code the _information_; put that into some data location. Use code _only_ to express logical operations that manipulate data.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your favorite method for learning, (Mine too!) I suggest you test it out yourself. Under `window/analysis/profiler`, you can measure CPU time and some other stuff, and also Task Manager on Windows and Activity Monitor on Mac can tell you the RAM, CPU, GPU, etc. Unity has quite robust [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Profiler.html) about it and I'm sure you can find plenty of tutorials on the web.